# OCaml Syntax Error in Parser

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex

Can someone help me explain why I have a syntax error at this line: `let wordMap = StringMap.empty`? This is contained in an .mll file. The module StringMap is defined above.

```
let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
    let wordlist =
        let rec next l = match token lexbuf with
            EOF -> l
            | Word(s) -> next (s :: l)
        in next []

    let wordMap = StringMap.empty in 
        let wcList  = StringMap.fold (fun word count l -> (string_of_int count ^ " " ^ word) :: l) wordMap [] in 

        List.iter print_endline wcList;;
```

I know it prints nothing, this is just for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A declaration like:

```
let v = expr
```

can only appear at the outermost level of a module. It's the way to declare the global names of the module.

But you have such a declaration (of `wordlist`) inside an expression:

```
let lexbuf = ... in
let wordlist = ...
```

In all places other than the outer level of a module, `let` must be followed by `in`. This is the way to declare a local variable (in any expression).

```
let v = expr1 in expr2
```

I'm not clear which of your names you want to be global. But one way to solve the problem would be to remove the first `in`. Then you would have three global names, `lexbuf`, `wordlist`, and `wordMap`.

Another way would be to add `in` after the definition of `wordlist`. Then you would have no global names.

Comment: I didn't include my complete code. I actually do have an in after wordMap, but I wasn't sure if it was necessary. Please check the code I changed, it still gives me a syntax error!

Comment: You need `in` after `wordlist` also. Not just after `wordMap`.

Comment: I tried that earlier and it worked, just wanted to see if there were alternatives/ understand the reason for the syntax error. Thanks again Jeffrey.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your `let-bindings`. This should work if I rewrite your as below:

```
    let main () =
      let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
      let wordlist =
         let rec next l = match token lexbuf with
            EOF -> l
          | Word s -> next (s :: l) in
         next [] 
      in
     wordlist

   let wordMap = StringMap.empty
```

The function `main` return `wordList` as the result.

Answer (score 0):

A golden rule for this sort of trouble: use a proper indentation tool, caml-mode, tuareg-mode or ocp-indent.  If these tools show an indentation different from your intention, it is often the case that you made a syntax error.